# Facebook user image storing in my database

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I am trying to develop a website where i could sign up using login.. happily i am successfull in retrieving minformation of the user.. Also the user profile pic is  displaying when i used the link below.

```
echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userdata['id'].'/picture">';
```

But i need to store this image to my database.. My database name is fbtest and table name is users.
The colum name where the picture to be stored is picture and the type is blob..
How could i insert this picture into my database.
The code for the authentication page is displayed below..

```
            <?php
            require 'lib/db.php';
            require 'lib/facebook.php';
            require 'lib/fbconfig.php';
            session_start();
            $facebook=$_SESSION['facebook'];
            $userdata=$_SESSION['userdata'];
            $logoutUrl=$_SESSION['logout'];
            $access_token_title='fb_'.$facebook_appid.'_access_token';
            $access_token=$facebook[$access_token_title];


            if(!empty($userdata))
            {
            echo '<h1>Login User Details</h1>';
            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userdata['id'].'/picture">';
            $img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userdata['id'].'/picture');
            echo "<br/>";
            echo '<b>Access Token: </b>'.$access_token;
            echo "<br/>";
            echo '<b>User ID: </b>'.$userdata['id'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Name: </b>'.$userdata['name'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>First Name: </b>'.$userdata['first_name'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Last Name: </b>'.$userdata['last_name'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Email: </b>'.$userdata['email'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Gender: </b>'.$userdata['gender'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Birthday: </b>'.$userdata['birthday'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Location: </b>'.$userdata['location']['name'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Hometown: </b>'.$userdata['hometown']['name'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Bio :</b>'.$userdata['bio'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Relationship Status: </b>'.$userdata['relationship_status'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo  '<b>Time Zone: </b>'.$userdata['timezone'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<br/>";

            $facebook_id=$userdata['id'];
            $name=$userdata['name'];
            $email=$userdata['email'];
            $gender=$userdata['gender'];
            $birthday=$userdata['birthday'];
            $location=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['location']['name']);
            $hometown=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['hometown']['name']);
            $bio=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['bio']);
            $relationship=$userdata['relationship_status'];
            $timezone=$userdata['timezone'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`, `hometown`, `bio`, `relationship`, `picture`) 
            VALUES ('$facebook_id','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$hometown','$bio','$relationship','$img')")  ;

            echo "<br/>";

             echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout Facebook</a>';
             }
             else
             {
              header("Location: fblogin.php");
             }
             ?>
```

Any help please???

Comment: Why would you want to store the actual images in your database in the first place? You are _required_ to keep them up-to-date, so that when a user changes their profile picture on Facebook, ideally it should reflect in your app immediately as well – so you are better off just taking that echo statement you already have to embed their profile picture wherever needed, and let Facebook’s CDN do the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But i dont need it to change. In my website i am taking the profile picture from database. So i need the picture in my database as user can change it to any other picture if needs from my website

Answer (score 1):

Here is two suitable you for storing picture in database.

After calling facebook graph api you will be able to get the profile picture url after that you can proceed with following two ways.

1. Add a profile picture column in your user table and insert the image path in this column directly.

OR

2. If you wand to add profile picture in picture column(blob object) then first convert the image url into base64 and then insert the base64 encoded data into your picture column.

Here is the code for converting a image into base64.

```
<?php

$imgPath = 'http://abcd.com/profilepicture/mypic.png'; // Facebook profile picture   will     replace here.
$imgdata = file_get_contents($imgPath);
$imgBase64Data = base64_encode($imgdata);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`, `hometown`, `bio`, `relationship`, `picture`) 
        VALUES  ('$facebook_id','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$hometown','$bio','$relationship','$imgBase64Data')")  ;
```

?>

Hope this will help you.

Thanks
Dinesh Pal

?>

Comment: I just used  the below code as the url and used it for get_file_contents(url).. But the image is stored as .bin file??$url='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userdata['id'].'/picture';

Comment: Also is How could i get the correct url of the profile picture from the graph api?

Comment: For getting the facebook profile picture of a user using the graph api please use this one.  https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userdata['facebookID'].'?fields=picture&access_token='.$access_token['access_token']